# Striping last directory from path with regex in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, url, path

I have a list of documents that I've collected using `Dir.glob` in Rails 3.

The result is a list of paths similar to the following:

```
/home/danny/nurserotas/GREEN WEEK 2ND JAN 2012.xls
```

What I would like to achieve is striping everything up, and including, the last forward slash. So the result for the above path is:

```
GREEN WEEK 2ND JAN 2012.xls
```

I'm going to be using these as links so I'm not sure if replacing the spaces with %20 is a good idea or not.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most crude way:

```
path = /home/danny/nurserotas/GREEN WEEK 2ND JAN 2012.xls
path.split('/').last # => GREEN WEEK 2ND JAN 2012.xls
```

This can also be done: `File.basename(path)`

Comment: Does File.basename(path) strip the file extension?

Comment: It won't. Checked it again :)

Comment: Great, thanks! Just need to work out how to strip the extension now then!

Comment: `File.extname` gives the extension including the '.' `File.basename(path).split('.').first` would give just the filename sans the extension. Or, if you can be sure that all the files may have only a three letter extension, `File.basename(path)[0...-4]` will also do the same although it will fail if the file has an extension that is not a 3 letter one(.jpeg/.mpeg/.mp4 etc)

Answer (score 7):

This is the way I'd recommend.

```
File.basename("/home/danny/nurserotas/GREEN WEEK 2ND JAN 2012.xls")
```

As a bonus, if you need to strip off any extension:

```
File.basename("/home/danny/nurserotas/GREEN WEEK 2ND JAN 2012.xls", ".*")
```